# How do I give space in between text in textview?

Tags: android, textview, space

I need to make something like this according to Android screen bound,

```
 S             M             T              W               T              F               S
```

I am doing like this:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="S       M       T        W        T        F       S" />
```

This is not working properly, not according to device screen bound.
 I need something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="S""10dp""M""10dp""T""10dp""W""10dp""T""10dp""F""10dp""S""10dp" />
```

Comment: so u wanna fill device screen? and is this letter fixed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can use it.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A&#160;B&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;C"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain what this actually does?

Comment: &#160; is Entity Number for non-breaking space.http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: dude, it is givin space but not much i need to give more space, i've changed the value from 160 to 1000 but didn't work.

Comment: actually the required space between my value is more than showin over here.. i gave more space when i am askin the question but stackoverfloow showin less spcae btw dese values

Comment: @Steve There is no effect by changing 160 to 1000.This is entity number for non breaking space so u should copied @#160; multiple times.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `letterSpacing` attribute for spacing between letters:

```
android:id="@+id/txt_work"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:typeface="serif"
android:layout_below="@+id/txt_wecm"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:textSize="32dp"
android:letterSpacing="0.1"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:text="World"
```

Comment: It also adds spaces before the first letter and after the last letter, but it works for my need now.

Comment: nice, i have upvoted as this is the correct way. but this works on api>20 (api 21 and above).

Answer (score 4):

USE Unicode Character [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm) `TextView` support this

try this

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
  android:text="@string/days" />
```

put this in  String.xml

```
<string name="days">S\u00A0M\u00A0T\u00A0W\u00A0T\u00A0F\u00A0S</string>
```

**EDIT 1**

it is fulfill your requirement but not efficient way till you not find solution with one `TextView` you can try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="S" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="M"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="T" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="W" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="T" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="F" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="S" />
```

Comment: will you please explain it little bit?

Comment: hey this fulfill your requirement but not efficient way till you not find solution with one TextView you can try like this

Answer (score 0):

*Letter-spacing in the TextView -*

> **android:textScaleX**
>
> Sets the horizontal scaling factor for the text.
>
> Must be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

You can increase the scaling factor depending upon the scale that you need between letters.

Android docs for [android:textScaleX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AtextScaleX).

Comment: This stretches the text. It doesn't add space in between the characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some space between Text in textView, you can use android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"

you can try like that:-

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
        android:text="hi
                     hello"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<span style=letter-spacing:10px>TEXT</span> "));
```

But i dont if this works

Comment: List of supported tags for textview - http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html